# SoapUI mockservice - Groovy Script - how to send xml request nodes to mock response

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am newbie with soapui and groovy. 
I am trying to send mock response with same requested nodes along with original values

SOAP Request contains below tags and I want these nodes should appear in my mock response as is, I am not sure how I can achieve it

```
 <Params>
    <ORArray>
        <ORN>1234</ORN>
        <ORN>1235</ORN>
        <ORN>1236</ORN>
        <ORN>1237</ORN>
    </ORArray>
    <ORVolArray>
        <ORVOL>54242</ORVOL>
        <ORVOL>54243</ORVOL>
        <ORVOL>54244</ORVOL>
        <ORVOL>54245</ORVOL>
    </ORVolArray>
    <ORPRArray>
        <ORPR>1414</ORPR>
        <ORPR>1415</ORPR>
        <ORPR>1416</ORPR>
        <ORPR>1417</ORPR>
    </ORPRArray>
</Params>
```

I am trying below code but not able to include request tags in mock response

```
def holder = util.getXmlHolder(mockRequest.requestContent)
def params = holder.getDomNodes("//*:Body/*:abc/*:xyz/*:Params").toString()
context.setProperty("Params", params)
```

updated mock response to replace with requested content but it is not working

```
<Params>${params}</Params>
```

Comment: Would you please show the desired response message as well for clarity?

Comment: Rao, as mentioned in question I want these nodes appear as is in mock response

Comment: appreciate if full desired response is specified in the question.